# image loop infinitely after clicking

Tags: javascript, image, loops

something wrong with my this code, the images are supposed to loop infinitely every 1 second after i click the start button. but when i clicked, it showed only the first image then stuck.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <h1> The traffic script</h1>

  <p> <button type="button" onClick="Cool()"><h2>Start</h2></button> </p>

  <script>
    function Cool() {

      setInterval(function() {
        Timer()
      }, 1000);
      //This will call the Timer function - units are milliseconds

      function Timer() // Complete the Timer() function by adding conditional statements to display the images
      {
        var list = [
          "https://i.ibb.co/Km3c7Lb/capture0002.jpg",
          "https://i.ibb.co/DL4N0K6/capture0002.jpg",
          "https://i.ibb.co/VqnpV4G/capture0001.jpg"

        ];

        var index = 0;
        index = index + 1;
        if (index == list.length) index = 1;
        var image = document.getElementById('red');
        image.src = list[index];
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <img id="red" src="https://i.ibb.co/Km3c7Lb/capture0002.jpg">
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It looks like you are setting `index = 0` every time `Timer()` executes. You might want to define/initialize that variable outside of the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you use the same index every time.

```
   var index = 0;
    index = index + 1;
    if (index == list.length) index = 1;
    var image = document.getElementById('red');
    image.src=list[index];
```

It is always 1.

1. You need to move the declaration out of the function.
2. Increment it AFTER you use it.
3. Also, you should reset it to 0, not 1, when it reaches the end.

outside of callback

```
   var index = 0;
```

in callback

```
    var image = document.getElementById('red');
    image.src=list[index];
    index = index + 1;
    if (index == list.length) index = 0;
```